# Trouble installing OPENSEA-JS via npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install opensea-js, at the moment I have installed web3 js. I keep on getting this error (refer below).
I have looked online, and someone wrote that git was the problem, I installed git but it is still not working.

My error when installing

```
C:\Users\fisher\Desktop\Project\test\new js>npm install --save opensea-js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\fisher\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-16T13_54_37_285Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: OS? Node.js and npm versions?

Comment: Windows 11, node 16.14.2, npm 8.5

Comment: I have the same environment and it works. Did you try on WSL 2?

Comment: @Anatoly is that required, I would prefer to just run it on vanilla windows

Comment: Just to compare results